# VB - How to dynamically add items on TOP of listview

Tags: sql, vb.net, listview, dynamic, addition

I have a listview in VB.net that I'm filling from a table in my SQL database. The listview refreshes every period of time (using a timer) and I want every dynamically added item to be added on the **TOP** of the listview.

Here's my code:

```
Dim itm as Listviewitem

 arr(0) = Date.Now.ToString
 arr(1) = Table.item("no")
 arr(2) = Table.item("datain")
 arr(3) = Table.item("message")

 itm = New ListViewItem(arr)
 ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Insert` method instead of `Add`, like this:

```
ListView1.Items.Insert(0, itm)
```

Note: 0 is the index of the first item in the list, so this puts it at the beginning.

Comment: Did it give an error or just not put the item at the top of the list? By the way, it is helpful to list all of the things you have tried in your post that way people will not suggest things that you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simply adding the item to the list, use the insert function :

```
ListView1.Items.Insert(0, itm)
```